# Retrieving rows from in sequel gem

Tags: ruby, postgresql, rake, sequel

i am trying to retrieve a row from a dataset 
my model class is

require 'sequel'
class Item < Sequel::Model
end

and one my hello.rb file is

```
require "rubygems"
require './post'
require "sequel"
require './item'
# connect to an in-memory database
#DB = Sequel.connect('postgres://ritesh:newpassword@localhost')

puts Item.filter(:id =>'1').first
```

its giving me output

```
#<Item:0xb693996c>
```

i want to get all the columns of the row whose id field is 1 what should be the query??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
puts Item.filter(:id =>'1').first.inspect
```

or

```
puts Item.filter(:id =>'1').first.to_yaml
```

(for better formatting if you have `yaml` required in your code like so `require 'yaml'`)